# Get json from webview

Tags: json, wordpress, flutter, dart, wordpress-rest-api

I have a wordpress website. I am getting the json data from its post rest api url "/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?orderby=date&order=desc".

But the main issue for me is that website is using the Cloudflare Under Attack mode so a challenge screen is visible to user when first time visiting. So if I try to use some http client like "http" in flutter, I can not get the data.

So I am trying to load an invisible webview at start and load the json data from webview and then convert that data to json and then will display in list.

But the issue is that I could not get the json data from the webview as I am very new in Flutter, so please help me.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

An example for you. If you have the string content of page you can initiate initial url  Uri.dataFromString or if you have the url you can pass it through. I can read the html response of the WebView page with _controller.evaluateJavascript("document.documentElement.innerHTML") this method. webview_flutter: ^1.0.7 Using this plugin < Try it;
Note: evaluteJavascript may have a method that can read json like innerMap innerJson but I don't know it exists or not

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(
      body: WebView(
        initialUrl: new Uri.dataFromString(widget.d3sc, mimeType: 'text/html').toString(),

        onWebViewCreated: (controller) {
          _controller = controller;
        },
        javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
        gestureNavigationEnabled: true,
        onPageFinished: (_) {
          readResponse();
        },
      )

    );
  }

  void readResponse() async
  {
    String paymentIdx;
    String conversationIdx;
    String conversationData;
    List<String> liste;

    setState(() {
      _controller.evaluateJavascript("document.documentElement.innerHTML").then((value) async {

        if(value.contains("name=\"paymentId\"")){
    
   ...........
    ................
```